# Slide down menu in Java

Tags: java, swing, menu, accordion, slide

I'm trying to create a slide down (If that's the correct term) in Java.
I can't seem to find a fitting Swing control to achieve this.

This is the effect I would try to reach.
[image: Layout]

Like the menu of "Swing Containers" and "Swing menus" is visible, but the menu of "Swing Windows" is just a simple bar with a + sign.

Anyone an idea how I get this layout with the GUI editor of Netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the posted example, you're looking for a collapsible component.

You could spend the time making your own, things to look out for are the layout manager that the component resides in, if it does not honour the preferred size of the components, it won't work (ie `BorderLayout` would not be a good choice to host this type of component in)

Personally, I use the `JXCollapsiblePane` from the [`SwingX`](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/) libraries, normally in combination with a `VerticalLayout` from the same library.